# What are "search volume trends" in AdWords?

Tags: seo, google-ads, google-keyword-tool

There was a change in Google Keyword Planner that added a "search volume trends" graph. How is it calculated?

The keyword "keyword1" has 800 average monthly searches while the search volume trends shows 3000 - why?

Comment: It is a long quest to find out what the figures in many Google tools actually means. I assume that all tools, besides Analytics, provide approximate values, rather than real values. Those figures are more useful to see the trends in the data, rather than making exact calculations.

Answer (score 1):

"Keyword1" frequency shows you the average frequency of the exact keyword, while the "volume trends" shows you the summary frequency of all the keyword variations.